# Mypy: Annotate function where return type depends on the type of an argument

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have a class that represents a normalized amount of memory.

```
class MemoryUnit(enum.Enum):
    """Units of memory."""

    GB = 'GB'
    TB = 'TB'
    PB = 'PB'
```

```
class Memory(BaseModel):
    """Normalized amount of memory."""

    amount: int
    unit: MemoryUnit
```

Now I want to implement basic arithmetics for this class. Addition, substraction and multiplication are easy to annotate:

```
def __add__(self, other: Memory) -> Memory: ...
def __sub__(self, other: Memory) -> Memory: ...
def __mul__(self, other: int) -> Memory: ...
```

I have a problem with division though. I see two use-cases for division:

- divide `Memory` by `Memory` and get a `float` (what is the ratio between two amounts of storage).
- divide `Memory` by `int` and get `Memory` (what is the amount of `Memory` if divided evenly among `n`)

Is there a way in mypy to annotate a function with this specific signature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) allows you to register multiple different signatures of a function. Functions decorated with `@overload` are ignored at runtime — they are just for the type-checker's benefit — so you can leave the body of these functions empty. Typically, you'll just put a literal ellipsis `...`, a docstring, or `pass` in the body of these functions. Also, you'll need to make sure there is at least one concrete implementation of the function for use at runtime.

```
from typing import overload, Union

class Memory(BaseModel):
    """Normalized amount of memory."""

    amount: int
    unit: MemoryUnit

    def __add__(self, other: Memory) -> Memory: ...
    def __sub__(self, other: Memory) -> Memory: ...
    def __mul__(self, other: int) -> Memory: ...

    @overload
    def __div__(self, other: Memory) -> float:
        """Signature of `Memory.__div__` if an instance of `Memory`
        is divided by another instance of `Memory`
        """

    @overload
    def __div__(self, other: int) -> Memory:
        """Signature of `Memory.__div__` if an instance of `Memory`
        is divided by an `int`
        """

    def __div__(self, other: Union[int, Memory]) -> Union[Memory, float]:
        """[Your actual runtime implementation goes here]"""
```