# How to type-annotate a Python function to mark it as returning None only when the input is None?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

There is a typical pattern for data conversion in our code: when the value is None, we let it pass through. E.g.,

```py
def capitalize(value):  
    if value is None:  
        return None  
    return value.capitalize()
     
# usage example:
assert capitalize(None) is None
assert capitalize("hello world") == "Hello world"
```

I can annotate it like this:

```py
from typing import Optional


def capitalize(value: Optional[str]) -> Optional[str]:  
    if value is None:  
        return None  
    return value.capitalize()
```

Looks OK, but the following code

```py
capitalize("Hello world").split()
```

will always make mypy complain.

```
error: Item "None" of "Optional[str]" has no attribute "split"
```

Is there a way to express with type annotations the conversion rule "None is always converted to None, and str is always converted to str?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like a use case for [Generics](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#type-variables-with-value-restriction) with a value restriction.

The code below basically says `T` can be either a `str` or `None`, and the function definition says "this function returns the same type as what came in".

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", str, None)

def capitalize(value: T) -> T:
    if value is None:
        return None
    return value.capitalize()

capitalize("Hello world").split()
```

Running `mypy` on the above code seems to work fine, and:

```py
capitalize(None).split()
```

causes `mypy` to complain: `error: "None" has no attribute "split"` which I think is what you're after.

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks a lot for the solution. 

I noticed, though, that I inadvertently simplified my use-case, and in a few examples, the returning type is different from the input, like `return None if value is None else int(value)`.

Do you know if there is a way to generalize the solution for this case?

Comment: I can't think of anything immediately obvious. I suppose you could consider refactoring your code so that `None` is handled separately higher in the call chain, which could give mypy stricter types to work with (and catch more bugs), but it might be quite a bit of work...

Comment: just a note you have a `Generic` import which appears unused.

Comment: good catch, thanks! I've updated the answer

Comment: @RomanImankulov for those more complex cases, you can use typing.overload https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68842887/mypy-annotate-function-where-return-type-depends-on-the-type-of-an-argument/68843617#68843617